# Should I learn Actionscript 3 along with Javascript to make web games?

Tags: javascript, actionscript-3, flash, actionscript

Hello(my first post on stack overflow)
I wanted to ask that should I learn Actionscript 3 or not, Am Already learning Javascript on Codecademy (20% completed). Someone suggested me to learn AC 3 and get the Flixel tuotorials on new grounds,Should I learn AS3 along or just focus on JS. Purpose for learning a language is to make 2d scroller web games,that works on smart phones and tablets.

Comment: Flash (AS3 host technology) does not work on iPhone and is not installed by default on Android. So AS3 is mostly useless for you now.

Comment: This question is not appropriate with this web page. Please read this http://sscce.org/

Comment: You do mean web games and not apps? Flash now export apps that can be sold on Apple Store and played on iPhone. Same with android. But no, if you want to play them on apples iPhone browser, it won't work.

Comment: @Dmitry - It should be clarified that AS3 in the web browser is useless,  AS3 is still current for native applications on desktop/mobile including the iPhone and Android.

Answer (score 4):

It is up to you. Usually, people are using game engines to create games, like Unity3D, Unreal. You can create games in Unity3D with Javascript. As for ActionScript (and this is my opinion) - it's a dying technology, so I wouldn't recommend it.

Answer (score 3):

ActionScript can be cross compiled to iOS but I would recommend to look into more open or broadly used languages like JavaScript or C#. Both languages can be used to work with Unity and can also be used to develop cross platform applications (i.e. C# with Xamarin).

Answer (score 1):

ActionScript was the first language I learned and it's a really easy one to learn first. It sounds like you're already learning JavaScript, though, and JavaScript is comparable to ActionScript in many ways. Personally, I don't think there's any language that beats ActionScript in your ability to get something on the screen quickly, and that can be really gratifying, but in terms of languages you could use to make games that will run on mobile, ActionScript won't cut it. It's becoming more and more obsolete everyday, which sucks but it's how the industry goes. JavaScript with HTML5, on the other hand, is still expanding and has already become one of the most popular ways to make web games, especially mobile. I'd say stick with JavaScript to actually make the games you want to share with people, but for learning, ActionScript is great. I can understand if you don't want to learn a language if you won't be making any real games in it, but I still think it's a great learning tool.

Answer (score 0):

Actionscript is a dying language and Flash doesn't work on iOS, so it's really not what you're looking for in terms of the project you are looking to develop.

On the other hand Actionscript is a great language to help you develop your knowledge of object-oriented programming, and everything you learn using Actionscript could be applied to something called 'Haxe' which would be ideal for your project and is also capable of working with Flixel.

Learning something new is never a waste of time.

Comment: Flash (Animate CC) has some webgl exporter though, no idea how well those work on mobiles.. but still i'd use some javascript framework: https://html5gameengine.com/